# JavaScript on input event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with CSS animations, when form field is selected labels animate out and when text is filled labels shouldn't animate back. And this works for input fields but not with textarea. Can't seem to find the problem, and I've been playing with it for some time now.

This is my JS code:

```
    <script>
    (function() {
        // trim polyfill : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim
        if (!String.prototype.trim) {
            (function() {
                // Make sure we trim BOM and NBSP
                var rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;
                String.prototype.trim = function() {
                    return this.replace(rtrim, '');
                };
            })();
        }

        [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('input.input_field', 'input-textarea.input_field-textarea') ).forEach( function( inputEl ) {
            // in case the input is already filled..
            if( inputEl.value.trim() !== '' ) {
                classie.add( inputEl.parentNode, 'input--filled' );
            }

            // events:
            inputEl.addEventListener( 'focus', onInputFocus );
            inputEl.addEventListener( 'blur', onInputBlur );
        } );

        function onInputFocus( ev ) {
            classie.add( ev.target.parentNode, 'input--filled' );
        }

        function onInputBlur( ev ) {
            if( ev.target.value.trim() === '' ) {
                classie.remove( ev.target.parentNode, 'input--filled' );
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

EDIT: This was the problem, code was going like this:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('textarea.input_field-textarea', 'input.input_field'))
```

Instead of removing those 2 extra '':

```
 document.querySelectorAll('textarea.input_field-textarea, input.input_field'))
```

Thanks to all for help!

Comment: try to change this "input-textarea.input_field-textarea" to this "textarea.input_field-textarea"

Comment: Is there a browser implementing `document.querySelectorAll()` that requires a shim for, and doesn't implement, `String.prototype.trim()`?

Comment: i think that problem may be here: `document.querySelectorAll('input.input_field', 'textarea.input_field-textarea') )`
Because when I only leave textarea part it works, when I put both only first one works, when I switch positions only first one works.

Comment: So this was the problem all along `document.querySelectorAll('input.input_field', 'textarea.input_field-textarea')` should be `document.querySelectorAll('input.input_field, textarea.input_field-textarea')`. Those '' were unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Change the `input-textarea.input_field-textarea` selector to `textarea.input_field-textarea`. There's no such `<input-textarea/>` element:

```javascript
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input.input_field', 'textarea.input_field-textarea')).forEach(function(inputEl) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: @FallenRider Do your `<textarea>` elements have `class="input_field-textarea"`?